# How can I change destination domain in macOS Sonoma?

Tags: terminal, network, firewall

for example, whenever an console command like `git clone https://github.com/...` or `wget https://github.com/...` which makes a remote call to github.com, change the actual call to an other domain like `https://githubfast.com/...`

PS. I've tried setting redirection rule in pfctl, but it doesn't work at all.

this is what I've tried:

made a config file defining redirection rule in `/etc/pf.anchors/redirection/github`:

```
rdr pass on en0 inet proto tcp from any to github.com port = 443 -> githubfast.com port 443
```

and referencing the rule in `/etc/pf.conf`

```
scrub-anchor "com.apple/*"
nat-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "com.apple/*"
rdr-anchor "redirection" <-- added
dummynet-anchor "com.apple/*"
anchor "com.apple/*"
load anchor "com.apple" from "/etc/pf.anchors/com.apple"
load anchor "redirection" from "/etc/pf.anchors/redirection" <-- added
```

then let the pf reload the configuration with command

```
sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.confg
```

I guess maybe pfctl redirection only works with ip?